# why I am getting "invalid command name "MZ"" on loading a dll on wish console?

Tags: c++, dll, tcl, swig

I have a library and I have generated tcl bindings for the same using swig. The dll thus generated is xyz_tcl.dll if my original lib dll us xyz.dll. but when I try to load the dll its says "invalid command name "MZ"". Can any one tell me what could be reason for it.

Comment: What does the code you're using to load the dll look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MZ` is almost certainly the first few bytes of the DLL (it's the “magic number” of the file format) so at a guess you're trying to do:

```
source xyz_tcl.dll
```

That won't work. It contains compiled C code that integrates with Tcl, but not a Tcl script. Instead, you need to do:

```
load xyz_tcl.dll
```

Of course, it *should* be build into a package (which is a directory containing the required DLLs and a file `pkgIndex.tcl`) which would then let you do something like this instead:

```
package require xyz
```

(The `pkgIndex.tcl` file contains instructions on how to define the package using the other files, through `load` and `source` as necessary.)

Comment: Technically, it's only part of the magic number; there are other bits further into the file that identify what sort of executable content it contains. That's not really very important here though. It's interpreting the “MZ” as a command because it's probably followed by a zero byte; a little-documented feature of Tcl is that an ASCII NUL is a command terminator in a script (just like a newline or semicolon).

Answer (score 2):

I think that something (tcl?) is trying to execute the DLL as a script - the first two bytes of a Windows executable file are 'M' and 'Z'.

For historical reasons, every Win32 executable has a small 16-bit MS-DOS header just before the actual Win32 PE header, and the signature bytes for the 16-bit header are "MZ".